Database json file and angular deployment
I am using GitHub pages to view my angular application (e-commerce store).
Products' data are in db.json file which normally I fetch using localhost/300 and run a watch command
What changes I have to do to make products data fetched automatically on the live version on GitHub pages
I tried to put the data in api.jsonbin.io and fetch it suing:
productsApiUrl = "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/bin ID/latest";
but i have this error 400
I tried to put the db.json file in assets and fetch it using httpClient, but I found myself in an infinite loop of code modification to avoid errors

you have to start a JSON server, on hosting sites like firebase or vite! Then use this server on your angular application. Because I believe you want to add/remove items from the JSON file and the application should detect these changes so I am recommending this server approach,

To fetch the products to get data from the assets/db.json file.
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productsApiUrl = '/assets/db.json'; // Point to your local assets folder

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.productsApiUrl);
  }
}

